# How do I write to Excel cells so that they are formatted correctly with hidden "tick" marks

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

I have to replace a broken SSIS package that basically just combines the data from a number of different Excel files, and creates a single master file.  My C# desktop application is putting all the data into the Excel file correctly, but the one problem is that the original file, which was of type .xls, has some kind of hidden formatting on the cells.

When you just view the data in the cells, it looks normal, but when you click on a cell and view it in the edit box, there is a tick mark (it looks like this ') in front of the data.  Editing it out does nothing, it just reappears.

I am guessing it is a "cheater" way to force the data to be of type character, since Excel is such a stinker about turning text which is made up of only numbers into a cell of type number, even if you write it as a string.

I wish we could do without it, but when we try to use a file without that formatting, it blows up the application.  And I do not have the time or budget to rewrite the application.

How can I duplicate this "tick" mark in the files which I am writing?  Currently I'm using EPPlus for writing, but I can also use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

If this is too difficult, I would also be open to someone telling me how to manually edit the file after I have created it programatically, and just add the cell formatting to the data.

Comment: Just append a single quote to any number you want to store as text in an excel cell